# Excel/VBA - How to check the top three and if equal then check based on custom rank?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data:

| Value | Percentages | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 67% | 3 |
| B | 57% | 4 |
| C | 43% | 5 |
| D | 38% | 1 |
| E | 67% | 2 |
| F | 57% | 6 |

In Excel (either **formulas** or **VBA**), how would I be able to generate a top three based on first the percentage value - and if the percentages of two or more are equal, then based on rank?

So for example 67% is found twice in column `Percentages`. However, the second time 67% is found it has a rank of 2, so the first value for the top three would be `E` and the complete top three would look like this:

```
1: E
2: A
3: B
```

I don't even have an idea to start with. I can use the `=LARGE` formula, but that will only give me the value of the highest and if the value is found in there multiple times, then I don't know from which one it took it. And it also doesn't take into account the custom ranking..

Comment: Thinking about writing a UDF for earlier versions of Excel - would  results in a single cell like E,A,B be acceptable, or should they be on separate rows?

Comment: It would be acceptable for me as I would be able to then maybe write some VBA to put them on separate rows myself. And if I succeed, I will write it in a comment below your UDF so that future generations can be helped as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a UDF that should work in  most versions of Excel (tested in Excel 365). I have chosen to avoid sorting and just repeatedly find the maximum subject to the two conditions. Assumes all percentages and ranks are positive values but can tolerate blank rows.

```
Function ListTopValues(r As Range, Optional topN As Integer = 3)

    Dim arr() As Variant, used() As Boolean
    Dim percent As Double, rank As Double
    Dim maxPercent As Double, maxRank As Double
    Dim value As String, maxValue As String, result As String
    Dim rows As Long, n As Long, i As Long, u As Long
    
    ' Transer range to array
    
    rows = r.rows.Count
    
    ReDim used(rows)
    
    arr = r.value
    
    ' Loop over number of values required
    
    For n = 1 To topN
        maxValue = ""
        maxRank = 0
        maxPercent = 0
        u = 0
        
        ' Loop over rows of data
        
        For i = 1 To rows
            value = arr(i, 1)
            percent = arr(i, 2)
            rank = arr(i, 3)
            
            ' Check if row already used and copy maximum so far
    
            If Not used(i) Then
                If percent > maxPercent Or percent = maxPercent And rank < maxRank Then
                    maxPercent = percent
                    maxRank = rank
                    maxValue = value
                    u = i
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        If maxValue <> "" Then _
            result = result & maxValue & ","
    
        If u > 0 Then used(u) = True
    
    Next n
    
    If Len(result) > 0 Then _
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

    ListTopValues = result
    
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, this works as you promised! The way it has to be used is that the columns as I have specified need to be in that order. Then you can call the function `=ListTopValues()` with the range from the first value of the first column until the last value of the last column. Very handy, thank you!

To split the values, I followed this tutorial:
https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/text-to-columns/

Comment: That's great! You could just return the three results as an array, but then you always have to select three cells and array-enter it for pre-365 versions of Excel, and I wasn't sure if that was what you wanted.

Comment: This is sufficient for my needs, many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have ***Excel-365*** then can try-

```
=SEQUENCE(3)&":"&INDEX(SORTBY(A2:A7,B2:B7,-1,C2:C7,1),SEQUENCE(3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun. So this wouldn't work if I would send the file to someone who doesn't have Excel 365?

Comment: Would you have a formula that would work with older versions of Excel?

Comment: It would be hard to make formula for older version.

Comment: All right thank you. Then I will wait before accepting this as the final answer as it's not universal given the different versions of Excel. But it's very helpful and I'm sure a lot of people will find this useful! Thanks!!